# android endless scroll using custom adapter (text, images) from json url, not adding second page items to list view

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

Can any one tell me how to implement endless scroll for an listview that using some custom adapter (loading text and images). Below is the code i tried, it loads the first page but not the second one, checked the scroll trigger event its working fine,

note: (in this example i tried to load the same json data again for testing purpose )

many thanks in advance!!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements EndlessListener {
TextView ver;
TextView name;
TextView api;

EndlessAdapter oEndlessAdapter;
EndlessListView oEndlessListView;

//URL to get JSON Array
private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";

//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
public static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
public static final String TAG_API = "api";

JSONArray android = null;
int iPageNo = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    oEndlessListView = (EndlessListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //EndlessAdapter adp = new EndlessAdapter(this, getDataFrmJson(iPageNo));
    //oEndlessListView.setLoadingView(R.layout.loading_layout);
    //oEndlessListView.setAdapter(adp);
    new JSONParse().execute();
}


private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
         ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
         name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
         api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.i("KUMAR", "Calling doInBackground()");
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = getDataFrmJson(iPageNo);
        return list;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
         try {
             int currentPosition = oEndlessListView.getFirstVisiblePosition(); 
             if( iPageNo == 1 ) {
                 oEndlessAdapter = new EndlessAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                 oEndlessListView.setLoadingView(R.layout.loading_layout);
                 oEndlessListView.setAdapter(oEndlessAdapter);
                 oEndlessListView.setListener(MainActivity.this);
                 iPageNo++;
             }else {
                oEndlessAdapter = new EndlessAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
                oEndlessListView.setAdapter(oEndlessAdapter);
             }
            oEndlessListView.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDataFrmJson(int page) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> osList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
        for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing JSON item in a Variable
            String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
            String api = c.getString(TAG_API);

            // Adding value HashMap key => value
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_API, api);

            osList.add(map);
        }
    }catch(JSONException je) {
        je.printStackTrace();
    }
    return osList;
}

@Override
public void loadData() {
    new JSONParse().execute();
}
```

}}

EndlessListView.java

```
{public class EndlessListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

private View footer;
private boolean isLoading;
private EndlessListener listener;
private EndlessAdapter adapter;

public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);    
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public EndlessListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public EndlessListView(Context context) {
    super(context);     
    this.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

public void setListener(EndlessListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    if (getAdapter() == null)
        return ;

    if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0)
        return ;

    int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;

    //Log.i("KUMAR", "list size: " + l);
    //Log.i("KUMAR", "isLoading status: " + Boolean.toString(isLoading));


    if (l >= totalItemCount && !isLoading) {
        Log.i("KUMAR", "totalItemCount: " + totalItemCount);
        // It is time to add new data. We call the listener
        this.addFooterView(footer);
        isLoading = true;
        Log.i("KUMAR", "Calling loadData()");
        listener.loadData();
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

public void setLoadingView(int resId) {
    Log.i("KUMAR", "Calling setLoadingView()");
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) super.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    footer = (View) inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    this.addFooterView(footer);

}


public void setAdapter(EndlessAdapter adapter) {        
    Log.i("KUMAR", "Calling setAdapter()");
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    this.adapter = adapter;
    this.removeFooterView(footer);
}


public void addNewData(EndlessAdapter eAdp) {
    this.removeFooterView(footer);
    setAdapter(eAdp);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    isLoading = false;
}


public EndlessListener setListener() {
    return listener;
}


public static interface EndlessListener {
    public void loadData() ;
}

}
```

EndlessAdapter.java

```
    {public class EndlessAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;


    public EndlessAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(convertView==null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_v, null);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vers); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name); // artist name
        TextView duration = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.api); // duration
        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); // thumb image

        HashMap<String, String> version = new HashMap<String, String>();
        version = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(version.get(MainActivity.TAG_VER));
        artist.setText(version.get(MainActivity.TAG_NAME));
        duration.setText(version.get(MainActivity.TAG_API));
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(thumb_image, "http://romio.com/assets/images/qa/noprofpicF480x480.png", R.drawable.loading);

        return view;
    }
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    {<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.example.androidhive.EndlessListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/getdata"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="5dp" />

   <!--  <Button
        android:id="@+id/getdata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
        android:text="@string/bnt_load" /> -->

</RelativeLayout>}

list_v.xml 
    {<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vers"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:hint="@string/ph_version_no"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="25sp" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/ph_version_name"
        android:textColor="@color/color_red"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vers"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/api"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:hint="@string/ph_version_api"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/vers"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_content_desc"
        android:src="@drawable/img_sample" />

</RelativeLayout>}
```

Comment: On your `postExecute` method, you recreate the adapter with the new itens (and only the new itens), and replace the previous adapter (that had the previous itens) when `iPageNo != 1`. You should add the new itens to the previous adapter on this case, not replace the previous one.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Bacause everytime you download the list data and replace the new data with the old one in the Arraylist. You should add the new json data to the current arraylist. Shortly make `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;` global and ADD all new data to this global list.